# How to erase error log contents from within a php file?

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to delete the contents of the error log before running `error_log();` to put new errors.

How may I do this from within a PHP file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way:

```
file_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');
error_log("Houston, we have a problem.", 0);
```

This will work only, if your user that is executing this has the permission to do this (Write access to this file).

Otherwise you can [set a other location for your runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) - in a location where you have access for this log. Like this:

```
ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'error.log');
#                    ^ full path with leading slash
```

---

If you want to backup the file instead you can do this with that oneliner:

`file_put_contents(pathinfo(ini_get('error_log'), PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php_error_backup_'.time().'.log', file_get_contents(ini_get('error_log')));`

Oneliner explained/expanded:

```
$save_location   = pathinfo(ini_get('error_log'), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$backup_filename = $save_location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php_error_backup_'.time().'.log';
$backup_content  = file_get_contents(ini_get('error_log'));
file_put_contents($backup_filename, $backup_content);
```